# Porque nesse caso tive que usar freopen?

Tags: c, funções, arquivo

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    FILE *ptr_file;

    ptr_file=fopen("archive.txt", "r");

    short size=0;
    char c;

    while(!feof(ptr_file)){

        c=getc(ptr_file);

        if(c=='\n'){

            size++;
        }
    }

    ptr_file=freopen("archive.txt", "r", ptr_file);

    printf("Size=%d\n\n", size);

    while(!feof(ptr_file)){

        c=getc(ptr_file);

        if(c=='\n'){

            size--;
        }
    }

    printf("Size=%d\n\n", size);

    fclose(ptr_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Basicamente esse código tem a função de ler o arquivo ate o seu final (`EOF`) contando o número de linhas e logo em seguida lendo novamente o arquivo até seu final, porém desta vez decrementando a variável que indica o número de linhas incrementada no *loop* anterior. Ok, onde que quero chegar com isso? Observe que se eu tirar a função `freopen` o código não funciona como o esperado, simplesmente o segundo *loop* não roda, mas agora porque ele não roda? Porque é necessário o uso da função `freopen` nessa situação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que já tem o arquivo aberto pois fez `fopen` no topo:

```
ptr_file=fopen("archive.txt", "r");
```

À medida que lê carateres do arquivo vai avançando a posição corrente até ao fim. Uma vez no fim, para voltar a ler do inicio precisa de se reposicionar no inicio. Uma forma de fazer isso é com [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/):

```
fseek ( ptr_file , 0 , SEEK_SET );
```

Em que `SEEK_SET` indica posicionamento a partir do inicio, e o `0` seriam o número de bytes a avançar do inicio.

Outra forma seria fechando e abrindo de novo o arquivo. Neste ultimo caso tem duas alternativas:

- `fclose` seguido de um novo `fopen`
- `freopen` que foi a opção que utilizou, e acaba por ser a mais direta no que toca a fechar e abrir

Respondendo agora à questão:

> Observe que se eu tirar a função freopen o código não funciona como o
>   esperado, simplesmente o segundo loop não roda

Não roda pois a posição já está no fim, logo não ha mais nada para ler. `freopen` faz posicionar de novo no inicio.